# display mongodb result in a google chart

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-visualization

i have a mongodb collection of clicked items of some stores.
If someone clicks on an item, the db add a json in this format:

```
{ 
"_id" : { "$oid" : "56cf06ce0b7707c83e5a8c64" }, 
"date" : { "$date" : 1456408270811 }, 
"name" : "Jura whisky", 
"store" : "56c9bfed942693bb745229ef" 
}
```

So, the db has different items, with different dates of different stores.
If I want to get all clicks of all items of a specific store, I use this query:

```
var id = global.actuallUser._doc._id;
            id = id.toString();
            global.databaseStatistic.collection(global.ARTICLEPRESS).aggregate(
                    [
                        {$match: {
                                $and: [
                                    {
                                        store: id,
                                        date: {
                                            $gte: new Date('12/01/2013'),
                                            $lte: new Date('12/01/2017')
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }},
                        {$group: {"_id": {name: "$name", day: {$dayOfMonth: "$date"},month: {$month: "$date"},year: {$year: "$date"}}, "count": {$sum: 1}}}
                    ]
                    ).toArray(function (err, result) {
                res.send(result);
            });
```

Now, I get an array of objects with the properties Name, day....
Is it possible to get this result in this format:

```
['date', 'name', 'count'],
['1.1.2000', Jura whisky, 400],
['1.1.2000', Potato, 460],
['1.1.2000', Pizza, 1120],
['2.1.2000', Jura whisky, 540]
```

So I can make a chart of the data with the google chart api.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are getting `results` JSON object as result of ajax call.

```
var columns = Object.keys(results[0]);
var data = results.map(function (result) {
  var tableRow = [];
  columns.forEach(function (col) {
    tableRow.push(result[col]);
  });
  return tableRow;
});
```

`data` will contain the table rows to be rendered by google chart.

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
columns.forEach(function (columnName) {
  dataTable.addColumn(columnName);
});

dataTable.addRows(data);
```

Comment: thanks, but now i get the exception : Error: Invalid type, count, for column "0".

Comment: this line : "dataTable.addColumn(columnName);"  dataTable.addColumn(type,columnName); fix the problem :-)